# Using printf in assembly 86, visual studio

Tags: assembly, x86

I wrote a simple program to use printf function in my code, but visual studio gives me the following error.

```
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _printf
```

Here's the source code :

```
.586
.model  flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

extern  ExitProcess@4   :   proc
extern  _printf         :   proc

.data
msg     BYTE    "Hello world",0

.code
main:

lea     eax,msg
push    eax
call    _printf

push    0                           ; return to os contorl point
call    ExitProcess@4

end main
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to link against the C runtime library. In VS15 you cannot simply add `msvcrt.lib` to the linker options because the loaded version has no _printf. Add instead a line to the top of the assembly file:

```
includelib "\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\msvcrt.lib"
```

and remove the leading underscore of `_printf` (VS15 automatically adds one).

Comment: I found the msvcrt.lib in `\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\msvcrt.lib` directory, but now I got the linker error, `error LNK1104: cannot open file '\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\msvcrt.lib'`.
Are you sure about the way of addressing?

Comment: @Mershdad: Oh! My VS15 on Win7 has the posted directory, whereas VS15 on Win10... Nevertheless: I've just successfully tested it with `...12.0\...\msvcrt.lib` (I copypasted your path) on Win10. If it continues to fail, download [MASM32](http://www.masm32.com/), install it and use its `msvcrt.lib` with full path.